# Batch programming setting ERRORLEVEL from failed FIND command

Tags: batch-file, error-handling, errorlevel

I have found the need to report an error level to a program that calls batch scripts.

The script will create a CSV log file that I would like to check in order to display whether the script was run successfully.

What I would like to say is something like

```
IF NOT FIND "[ERR" "test.csv"
```

or to say, that if the string `"[ERR"` is not in the output `ERRORLEVEL = 0 ELSE ERRORLEVEL = 1`

Hope this makes sense. I'm sure it is simple but setting error levels seems to be a royal pain in the a$se!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

FIND "[ERR" "text.csv" sets ERRORLEVEL to 0 if at least one `[ERR` is found, and 1 if no `[ERR` is found. You need a way to invert the logic.

If all you want to do is immediately return 0 if no `[ERR` found, or `1` if at least one `[ERR` found, then I would use the following:

```
find "[ERR" "test.csv" >nul && exit /b 1 || exit /b 0
```

If you want to capture the result in a variable to be returned later, then:

```
find "[ERR" "test.csv" >nul && set "err=1" || set "err=0"
```

or

```
find "[ERR" "test.csv" >nul
set /a "err=!%errorlevel%"
```

When you are ready to return the result

```
exit /b %err%
```

---

Below is my original answer that was accepted, yet was ***embarrassingly wrong*** :-(
Thanks Corey for pointing out the logic error. As he says in his comment, the faulty code below will only report an error if all of the lines have the `[ERR` text.

> FIND will set the ERRORLEVEL to 0 if found, 1 if not found. To reverse
>   the logic, simply use the /V option.
>
> ```
> find /v "[ERR" "test.csv" >nul
> ```
>
> If you have a variable set that indicates the errorlevel, then you can
>   use EXIT /B to set the ERRORLEVEL
>
> ```
> set err=1
> exit /b %err%
> ```

Comment: Hi dbenham,Thank you for your reply but unfortunately just adding /V seems to result in the Errorlevel always being set to 0. Also I've tried using this batch file to test the second response.FIND "[ERR" "test.csv" SET MYERROR = 1 EXIT /B %MYERROR% it should always return 1 when I echo %errorlevel% but it will only do this if the [ERR is not in the test.csv file! Am I doing something wrong with the syntax? All 3 statements are on separate lines but I don't seem to be able to start a new line to represent this! thank you in advance of your reply!

Comment: dbenham! After running through this again, I found that I had made what is  DOS schoolboy error! I put set err = 1 instead of err=1. For anyone else reading this, what this means is that, when you type SET ERR =1 the variable name is 'ERR ' not 'ERR'. Thank you!

Comment: Specifying `/V` will only result in a failure (ERRORLEVEL == 1) if *all* lines in the file contain the specified value. It reverses the test from *contains x* to *does not contain x*, with ERRORLEVEL being 0 if any lines are found that match the test.

Comment: @Corey - OMG, you are correct, my logic does not give the desired result! I will edit my answer. I am amazed no one ever pointed out the error in 5+ years, especially the OP.

Comment: Sorry about zombie posting... I was looking for this and found it was backwards.

Comment: @Corey - Hell, don't apologize. It is important that info like this gets corrected.

Answer (score 4):

Note that the IF command has the logic that it returns true if ERRORLEVEL is *greater than or equal to* the following number!  So

```
IF ERRORLEVEL 0 (...
```

returns true for all FIND commands.  What you need if you only want to test if a phrase is in a file:

```
find "string" "test.txt" > NUL & IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 ECHO String was found
```

Took me ages to work that out!

Comment: `&&` is a kind of shortcut for `IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1`, so you could change  your line to: `find "string" "test.txt" > NUL && echo  String was found || echo String was not found`

Answer (score 3):

This is the logic I've used in a BAT file previously.

```
find "string" "test.txt" > NUL & IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
    ECHO String was NOT found
) ELSE (
    ECHO String was found
)
```

You could put whatever commands you wish inside the IF/ELSE blocks.